# Random number in a button iterates itself! How can I remove it from iterating?

Tags: javascript, random

I created a button that generates random numbers, but if I click it more than once the set intervals adds up to the  existing interval and it becomes faster (I guess!) Is there a way to stop it without disabling the button/changing the id? Any clean method? Please help! Apologies if I'm not following forum etiquette; I'm new to this!

```
HTML:
<button  type="button" class="button" id="button" onClick="randomnumber()"> 
Click to start </button>


JAVASCRIPT:
function randomnumber(){
var myVar = setInterval(function(){randomnumber1()}, 1000);
function randomnumber1(){
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 99));
    document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = x;

    }

}
```

Here is the link:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bJkjC

Comment: Why are you setting an interval?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declare a flag like `clicked` that becomes `true` after pressing the button:

```
var clicked = false;
function randomnumber(){
    if (clicked) { return; }
    clicked = true;
    var myVar = setInterval(function(){randomnumber1()}, 1000);
    function randomnumber1(){
        var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 99));
        document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = x;
    }
}
```

[**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ghBcx)

Comment: @user3865557 Then click `✔` button, in the left side of my answer. You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Make the interval variable global and use its value as a flag:

```
var myVar = null;

function randomnumber(){

if (myVar == null)
  myVar = setInterval(function(){randomnumber1()}, 1000);

  function randomnumber1(){
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 99));
    document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = x;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `clearInterval` to kill an existing interval?

```
var myVar = null;

function randomnumber(){
    if (myVar != null)
        clearInterval(myVar);

    myVar = setInterval(function(){randomnumber1()}, 1000);

    function randomnumber1(){
        var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 99));
        document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your heart is set on delaying 1 second before updating the random number use

setTimeout instead of setInterval.

setInterval sets an interval and repeatedly calls the function each time the interval expires.

setTimeout calls a function at the end of the timeout period.

```
function randomnumber(){
    var myVar = setTimeout(function(){randomnumber1()}, 1000);
    function randomnumber1(){
        var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 99));
        document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = x;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following.

```
var myVar = null;
function randomnumber(){
  if(myVar==null) {
    myVar = setInterval(function(){randomnumber1()}, 1000);
    function randomnumber1(){
      var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 99));
      document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = x;
    }
  }             
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

```
function randomnumber(){
    var myVar = setInterval(function(){randomnumber1()}, 1000);
    function randomnumber1(){
        var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 99));
        document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = x;
    }
    document.getElementById("button").onclick=null;
}
```

If you don't need the function anymore just get rid of it onclick.